# pull-up resistor for MOSI pin of SPI communication

Tags: spi

I want to know how to calculate pull-up resister values for MOSI pin of SPI communication,details are,
1.speed of communication 12Mbps.
2.master is controller (datasheet:R01DS0190EJ0130) and Slave is Flash(AT45DB041E).
3.I am using Simple SPI mode.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. I'm pretty sure it will break the bus at 12Mbps. Why do you think you even need pull-ups to begin with? This isn't I2C.

Comment: so are u telling there is no need of pull-ups for SPI communication

Comment: usually not, some devices can require it (on the MISO line), but that's not typical, especially at higher speeds

Comment: ok,if i want to use ,what value of pull-up is recommended.

Comment: The value would have to be determined by the *reason* you want to use one at all.  Since you have not proposed a reason, there's no basis in your question to make a determination.

Comment: You shouldn't use one unless you really need to, it can cause issues with your edges. If you do need one, it's not as easy as use "X" ohm resistors.

Comment: SPI uses push-pull driver. there is no need of pull-up on that line. To have Mode 0/3 you need to have pull-down/up on clock line alone. Chip select will have a pull-up resister. For MOSI line there is no pull-up required. When pull-up is not required what is the need to design it.

Comment: If you want to put it there, but have no clue why or which value, why do you want it? And why you want a pull-up instead of pull-down is another thing. If you want, put a random 10k resistor there and see if it still works.

Comment: thank you all,from the above discussion i understood that MOSI does not require pull-up.What about clock line? do i need pull-up there?

Comment: Let's get the biggest issue out of the way: Where did you get the idea you pullups *anywhere* in SPI and why do you want them?

Comment: i have seen I2C communication circuit,in that they used pul-ups  on data line and clock line thats why i am asking.

Comment: Well, I2C is not SPI. I2C is open collector drive so needs pull-ups.